# Auto update plist CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I have a project that has different targets based on the stage of development (Staging, Production, Develop). For each target, I have a plist file that goes with it.

My question is how can I automatically update each plist's `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` to be based off of the `Version` and `Build` that is set in my project's General Identity settings? (See image below for General Identity Settings [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO7Fb.png))

My `Info.plist` automatically updates because it is obviously the original plist, I just need to get my `Staging.plist`, `Develop.plist` and `Prod.plist` to automatically update like `Info.plist` does.

Is this possible, or do I just need to update each plist I have every time I change the Identity?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fastlane` to update the `version` and `build number` of multiple targets. For that you've to set up the `fastlane` with your project (one time effort but after that it is easy)

For more detail you can see the following links:

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/

https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to use a 3rd party for distribution.